# lalr(1) action table algorithm

Tags: algorithm

Could someone describe the algorithm to generate the needed tables (action, goto) from a given grammar for LALR(1)?

I have already read

1. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LALR_parser
2. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LR_parser

Edit
Finally I found out some interesting related pages in the dragon book, but whoever wants, can answer the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been a while since I last worked with LALR, but I found this doc that will most certainly help anyone wanting to understand LALR algorithms:

http://www.facweb.iitkgp.ernet.in/~niloy/Compiler/notes/LALRP.doc